# Проверить как отработала system();

Tags: c++

В чем минусы использования функции для удаления каталога?

```
system();
```

Как отследить код возврата, если каталог не удалился, потому что занят процессом?

```
string a = "cmd /c rd /s /q c:\\temp\\1";
system(a.c_str());
```

Comment: *"Как отследить код возврата, если каталог не удалился, потому что занят процессом?"*  [man system](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) --  посмотреть код возврата -- *`"...If all system calls succeed, then the return value is the termination status of the child shell used to execute command.        (The termination status of a shell is the termination status  of the last command it executes.)"`*

Comment: Предлагаю разбить данный вопрос на два, ибо *Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме.* И на вторую часть уже ответили в комментарии.

Comment: А почему не удалить каталог средствами C++? И почему потом - если уж с кодом возврата проблемы (кстати, `cmd /c` зачем? `system` же и так `cmd` вызывает) - почему не проверить, удалился ли он?

Comment: Средствами с++ надо править атрибуты всех файлов перед удалением. А проверять можно удалился или нет.

Answer (score 3):

У меня вполне нормально отрабатывает

```
cout << system("rd /s /q g:\\tmp\\test >nul 2>&1");
```

(`>nul 2>&1` - чтоб лишнего на экран не выводила...)

При занятости процессом выводит 32, при отсутствии каталога - 2, при успешном удалении - 0...

Comment: Не получается проверять код возврата. Файл запущен, функция возвращает 0, файл не удалился. Если проверять его наличие, то тогда можно понять, как она отработала. За отключение вывода в консоль спасибо.

Comment: Увы, воспроизвести ваше поведение (ну, в смысле, вашей программы) не могу...

Comment: Запускаете exe файл с каким нибудь приложением, и удаляете папку с ним с интервалом в пару секунд в цикле. Результат вызова выводите на экран. У меня код возврата 0 несколько раз)

Comment: Я же написал - код 32. Сколько бы раз не вызывал :) Что соответствует истине - https://ss64.com/nt/rd.html Компилировал VC++ 2019